# Using Roboguice in Tests in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, roboguice

So after spending a day or so trying to get robolectric to work with gradle using the [android-gradle-plpugin](https://github.com/JakeWharton/gradle-android-test-plugin) I read that [the creator thinks it's too much hassle and doesn't use it himself](https://github.com/JakeWharton/gradle-android-test-plugin/issues/4)

So thats a big enough reason for me not to use it either. However now I cannot find any docs on how to set up normal android tests to run on the emulator. Its seems they all relate to eclipse. How do I get normal Android testings running with Android studio. I presume I need to modify build.gradle but how do I do that?

I would also like to use roboguice to inject my dependencies into the test cases.

**EDIT**

So I took a stab in the dark and I tried this but the test returns false (a fail)

```
public class SearchTest extends ActivityTestCase {

    @Inject
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        RoboInjector injector = RoboGuice.getInjector(getActivity());
        injector.injectMembersWithoutViews(this);
    }

    public void shouldSerialise() {
         System.out.println("called should serialise");
        Assert.assertNotNull(objectMapper);
    }

}
```

**EDIT 2**

So I have tried a different approach. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.element84.com/easy-testing-with-android-studio.html) which does seem to run the test however I am having a problem with providing a manifest find as I get the following error,

> WARNING: No manifest file found at ./AndroidManifest.xml.Falling back
>   to the Android OS resources only. To remove this warning, annotate
>   your test class with @Config(manifest=Config.NONE).

I then used this test runner instead...

```
public class RobolectricGradleTestRunner extends RobolectricTestRunner {

    public RobolectricGradleTestRunner(Class<?> testClass) throws  org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError {
        super(testClass);
    }

    @Override protected AndroidManifest getAppManifest(Config config) {
        String manifestProperty = System.getProperty("android.manifest");
        if (config.manifest().equals(Config.DEFAULT) && manifestProperty != null) {
            String resProperty = System.getProperty("android.resources");
            String assetsProperty = System.getProperty("android.assets");

            return new AndroidManifest(Fs.fileFromPath(manifestProperty), Fs.fileFromPath(resProperty),
                    Fs.fileFromPath(assetsProperty));
        }
        return super.getAppManifest(config);
    }
}
```

With no luck. Would I be better reverting back to intellij and purely using maven?

Comment: I am considering dumping gradle at the moment. I can't see the advantages at all. Surely maven works just as well and doesn't disable libraries being used like gradle does?